# Glyphicon not showing up in browser

Tags: html, angular

I am learning angular and 
I want to show Glyphicon (Heart)on browser.
 full code: https://github.com/tsingh38/Angular2

My Component class:

**Heart.component.html** contains :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
```

i tried using "icon"as well

Heart.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heart',
  templateUrl: './heart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heart.component.css']
})
export class HeartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component ,NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import{CoursesComponent} from './courses/courses.component';
import{AuthorComponent} from './author/author.component';
import{StarComponent} from './star/star.component';
import{HeartComponent} from './heart/heart.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

@NgModule({
  declarations:[CoursesComponent,AuthorComponent,HeartComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}

app.component.html
```

i write something here and it should be displayed.

```
 <div>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
 </div>
 <app-heart></app-heart> 
 <app-star></app-star>
 <courses></courses>
 <author></author>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import { AuthorComponent } from './author/author.component';
import { AutoGrowDirective } from './directives/auto-grow.directive';
import { StarComponent } from './star/star.component';
import { HeartComponent } from './heart/heart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    AuthorComponent,
    AuthorComponent,
    AuthorComponent,
    AutoGrowDirective,
    StarComponent,HeartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Package.json**  I am not sure if needed

```
{
  "name": "angular2-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Console shows no errors.

In case some information is missing from my side please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have bootstrap or any library that includes glyphicon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add **`bootstrap.css`** in **`index.html`** page in **`<head>`** section as shown below,

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 ...
</head>
```

path can be your local path also.