# GlypIcon not showing in browser (Angular)

Tags: angular

I am just learning angular and I am running into problems which I can't seem to understand. Saw a solution here [Glyphicon not showing up in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145793/glyphicon-not-showing-up-in-browser)  but its not working for my code. I will appreciate any kind assistance. Thanks

The GlypIcon for star is not showing on my Chrome browser without any error on console.

**FavoriteComponent.html** contains:

```html
    <span
      class= "glyphicon"
      [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
      [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
      (click) ="onClick()"
    ></span>
```

**FavoriteComponent.ts**

```js
     import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

     @Component({
     selector: 'favorite',
     templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
     })
     export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
     @Input() isFavorite: boolean;
     constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
       }

     onClick (){
      this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
      }
     }
```

**app.component.ts**:
          import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```js
       @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       templateUrl: './app.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
       })

       export class AppComponent {
       post = {
       title : 'Angular app',
       isFavorite: true
         }
        }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
      import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

      import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
      import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
      import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
      import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
      import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';

      @NgModule({
      declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      CoursesComponent, 
      CourseComponent, FavoriteComponent
         ],
     imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule
       ],
      providers: [
      CoursesService
      ],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
     export class AppModule { }
```

I just want the star icon to show on my browser, its not showing. Thanks

Comment: Which version of bootstrap css did you try? Bootstrap v4 has [dropped glyphicons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/), so make sure you use Bootstrap v3 or lower if you want to use glyphicons.

Comment: Actually installed the latest bootstrap which is Bootstrap v4. Any alternative for glyphicons on V4? Thanks

Comment: Check this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/)

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I will take a look at it